# What's the canonical way to handle asynchronous work in Erlang?

Tags: erlang

I have experience in JavaScript and I am used to callbacks functions:

```
function myFun(arg1, arg2, successCB, failCB) {
  var sum = arg1 + arg2;
  if (sum > tooHigh) {
    failCB("too high!");
  } else {
    otherFun(sum, arg1, successCB, failCB);
  }
}
```

I can write the same code in Erlang:

```
my_fun(Arg1, Arg2, SuccessCB, FailCB) ->
  case Arg1 + Arg2 of
    Sum when Sum > ?TOO_HIGH ->
      FailCB(too_high);
    Sum ->
      other_fun(Sum, Arg1, SuccessCB, FailCB)
  end.
```

I find this approach reasonable from my experience, but I feel like I will need to do a lot of this in my code, so, apparently, there is a better way to manage these true/false/whatever scenarios.

Is this typical Erlang code? Is there some other way that I should be doing this?

Comment: Why not just use different function clauses? Or `case User of`?

Comment: You need to do your homework, since if you're trying to use the same approach to error handling in Erlang as you do in other languages, you're doing it wrong. Try searching for the Erlang "let it crash" philosophy, for example, and [here's a related question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4393197/erlangs-let-it-crash-philosophy-applicable-elsewhere).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JavaScript uses callbacks because you have a single thread and callbacks are the way that you transfer your state across context switches.

Callback functions are a generally-useful tool, but in JavaScript they're a *fundamental* tool because it's how asynchronous work gets done.

In Erlang, you can (and should!) use many processes. Within a single process, you can make synchronous, blocking calls because this doesn't affect system performance.

I'd expect the Erlang version of the above JS code to look like

```
my_fun(Arg1, Arg2) ->
  case Arg1 + Arg2 of
    Sum when Sum > ?TOO_HIGH ->
      too_high;
    Sum ->
      other_fun(Sum, Arg1)
  end.
```

There's no callbacks, because the functions return the values (`too_high` and maybe `{ok, Result}`). All the functions are blocking -- if `other_fun` is a network call, it might wait several seconds before returning. If parallelism is needed, you `spawn` as many processes as you like.